# Why can't a static class dict be constructed from another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Starting off with a few dict variables defined within a class context...

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    coloring = {u'DEBUG':u'magenta', u'WARNING':u'yellow',
        u'ERROR':u'red', u'INFO':u'blue'}
    colors =  dict(zip([u'black', u'red', u'green', u'yellow',
        u'blue', u'magenta', u'cyan', u'white'], map(str, range(30, 30 + 8))))
```

...I was intending to generate a derived dict variable that effectively cached the results of `colors[coloring[____]]`; the intended dict contents are shown below:

```
{'DEBUG': '35', 'WARNING': '33', 'ERROR': '31', 'INFO': '34'}
```

However, using two of the dictionary constructor formats described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) results in a runtime error message of `NameError: name 'colors' is not defined` (in spite of `colors` being defined immediately prior):

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    coloring = {u'DEBUG':u'magenta', u'WARNING':u'yellow',
        u'ERROR':u'red', u'INFO':u'blue'}
    colors =  dict(zip([u'black', u'red', u'green', u'yellow',
        u'blue', u'magenta', u'cyan', u'white'], map(str, range(30, 30 + 8))))
    print(colors) # test statement; colors is in scope here
    color_map = {k:colors[v] for k, v in coloring.items()}
```

.

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    coloring = {u'DEBUG':u'magenta', u'WARNING':u'yellow',
        u'ERROR':u'red', u'INFO':u'blue'}
    colors =  dict(zip([u'black', u'red', u'green', u'yellow',
        u'blue', u'magenta', u'cyan', u'white'], map(str, range(30, 30 + 8))))
    print(colors) # test statement; colors is in scope here
    color_map = dict([(k, colors[v]) for k, v in coloring.items()])
```

Why did the above code snippets not behave as expected?  Why was `colors` not in scope in the `color_map` constructor, even though it appears to otherwise be in scope within the class declaration?

(Ultimately, I was able to get the desired behavior using the below code block; I'm asking this question to understand why my previous attempts at a "cleaner" solution weren't working.)

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    coloring = {u'DEBUG':u'magenta', u'WARNING':u'yellow',
        u'ERROR':u'red', u'INFO':u'blue'}
    colors =  dict(zip([u'black', u'red', u'green', u'yellow',
        u'blue', u'magenta', u'cyan', u'white'], map(str, range(30, 30 + 8))))
    color_map = {}
    for k, v in coloring.items():
        color_map[k] = colors[v]
```